# Can not prepare INSERT statement in SQLITE, C API

Tags: c, sqlite

```
  /* DATABASE INIT */

ret = sqlite3_open_v2(dbfile, &DB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

if (SQLITE_OK != ret) {
    printf("Could not open database.\n");
    exit(1);
}

const char* zSql = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES (?)";
ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sites[DB, zSql, strlen(zSql), &s, NULL);

if (SQLITE_OK != ret) {
    printf("Could not compile statement '%s', got %d.\n", zSql, ret);
    exit(1);
}
```

Well, there you go. What's wrong?  sqlite3_prepare_v2 always fails.

Update:
I tried the suggestions so far, but no cigar.
I created the simplest case I could think of, with a schema:

```
CREATE TABLE abc(a INTEGER);
```

And the C code as above, still does not work, gets 'Could not compile statement'
got return code 26 which apparently means `SQLITE_NOTADB`. So it seems my database file is not... a database file. Strange, I will have to look into this.

The sqlite CLI accepts the file and can show the schema if I use the ".dump" command.

I changed the database file name from "data.db" to "data.sqlite". Now I get a return code of 1, SQLITE_ERROR, instead.

*Update:*
I was accessing the wrong file, AKA [user error](http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/frustrations/59fe/).
Accepting one of the answers that pointed out a syntax error in my unedited question.

Comment: What does SQLite return? Your code seems ok. Maybe it's a mismatch in the column/table name, or constraint violation?

Comment: @valdo, it is the only table so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try

```
const char* zSql = 
    "INSERT INTO abc (moderation_status, phonenumber, email) VALUES(?,?,?)";
```

assuming `moderation_status` `phonenumber` and `email` are the names of the fields in your table.

or:

```
const char* zSql = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES(?,?,?)";
```

The `?` is the placeholder for where the arguments will be inserted.

Comment: Beat me by a second!  I knew I shouldn't have done that last tweak to my answer :)

Comment: That's what you get for being detailed and explaining your answer :P

Answer (score 2):

You haven't supplied a list of values; you've supplied a list of names (presumably column names) where a list of values is needed.

You might need:

```
char* zSql = "INSERT INTO abc(moderation_status, phonenumber, email) "
             "VALUES('U', '212-234-6678', 'example@example.com')";
```

Or you might not bother with the column names:

```
char* zSql = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES('U', '212-234-6678',"
             "'example@example.com')";
```

Or you might use placeholders:

```
char* zSql = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
```

If you use placeholders, you'll have to provide the corresponding values when you execute the statement.  (But placeholders are generally the best solution - they avoid [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327) problems.)